# Could not find a required file. Name: index.html in react with docker compose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, deployment, docker-compose

I have my react app set up with create-react-app and I was trying to run it with Docker container and Docker compose. 
However, I got the following error when I ran it with Docker compose.

```
web_1     | Could not find a required file.
web_1     |   Name: index.html
web_1     |   Searched in: /usr/src/app/web_client/public
```

I am using Windows 10 and Docker quickstart terminal

Here is my folder structure:

```
vocabulary-app
   |
    web_client
         |
          node_modules/
          public/
          src/
          package.json
          package-lock.json
          Dockerfile
          yarn.lock
    docker-compose.yml
```

Here is the content of `docker-compose.yml`

```
  ### Client SERVER ###
  web:
    build: ./web_client
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_PORT=80
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./web_client/src:/usr/src/app/web_client/src
      - ./web_client/public:/usr/src/app/web_client/public
    links:
      - server
    command: npm start
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:9.0.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/web_client
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/web_client

COPY . .

RUN rm -Rf node_modules

RUN npm install

CMD npm start
```

I also tried to explore the file system in docker and got the following result:

```
$ docker run -t -i vocabularyapp_web /bin/bash
root@2c099746ebab:/usr/src/app/web_client# ls
Dockerfile  node_modules       package.json  src
README.md   package-lock.json  public        yarn.lock
root@2c099746ebab:/usr/src/app/web_client# cd public/
root@2c099746ebab:/usr/src/app/web_client/public# ls
favicon.ico  index.html  manifest.json
```

This one basically means that the `index.html` file is there, so I got more confused about the error message.

Does someone have solution to this?

Comment: Seeing as this is still only a month old I hope you somehow found an answer. I am currently coping with the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue when working deploying a React App using Docker on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

The issue was that I missed the step of copying the contents of the entire previous build to the working directory (`/app`) of the application.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Add this below as a step after the `RUN npm install` and before the `RUN npm run build` steps:

```
COPY . ./
```

**My Dockerfile**:

```
# Set base image
FROM node:latest AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and install packages
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy other project files and build
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# Set nginx image
FROM nginx:latest

# Nginx config
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Static build
COPY --from=builder /app/public /usr/share/nginx/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

**My docker-compose file**:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: my_app-frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: ${REACT_APP_API_URL}
    expose:
      - "3000"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

**Nginx for serving static files**:

Create a directory called `nginx` and then under the directory create a file called `default.conf`. The file will have the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires -1;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

**My .env**

Create a `.env` file where you will store your environment variables:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://my_api
```

That's it.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. What does your docker-compose.yml look like?

For the working directory, if there are front and back-ends, would the `WORKDIR` be `WORKDIR /app/frontend`?

Comment: Hi @peyo, I have updated my answer with my `docker-compose.yml` file and some other relevant configurations. If you have a **frontend** and **backend** then most times they are often dockerized separately and made to communicate with each other via API calls. You can give your `WORKDIR` any name of your choice anyways. It does not have to be *`app`, it can be `web`, `website`, `application` or any name of yours. Just ensure that you reference it appropriately wherever it is needed.

Comment: Please be aware, despite adding restart: always to your docker-compose file, it may seem as though your project is running, but in reality it can be crashing and restarting constantly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a docker-compose file, but I was able to get a similar react app to run with the docker command

`docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3001:3000 --rm app-name:dev`

I was then able to access my react app from `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

I did an explict COPY ./public/index.html and this problem went away
but similar error generated for index.js and index.css.
Doing same for these fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably not all the files were copied to WORKDIR
Check it by running,

```
docker exec <CONTAINER ID> ls <path/to/WORKDIR>
```